# How do I setText on a TextView that isn't in the current "active activity"

Tags: android, user-interface, textview

I have an activity which, when an item is selected. Starts a new thread setting the active call forwarding number and sets this number as the text of a TextView in another activity.

I tried this:

```
        newnumber[0] = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
        new PushNumberTask().execute(newnumber);
        TextView activeNumberTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activeNumberTextView);
        activeNumberTV.setText(newnumber[0]);
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException whenever it tries to set the text. What silly mistake am I making? I should mention that the number is in fact being changed on the server and in the user info. It's just that updating the text field from another activity is causing the exception.

***EDIT:** Simplified my problem a bit(i hope). I have a model class with SharedPreferences userInfo.getString("number")
I want to notify a TextView whenever this string is updated/changed. How do I go about doing this ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very bad practice.. What i would do is i'll send it through intent or use getter setter in some data class and when that activity comes to foreground i would set its Text... you can set it in `onActivityResult()`, or `onResume()` methods

Answer (score 0):

you should use SharedPreference object to get this.

```
SharedPreference s_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
Editor edit=s_pref.edit();
edit.putString("text","new_text");
edit.commit();
```

now in the activity's onResume() method,where you want to update textview,

```
SharedPreference s_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String s=s_pref.getString("text","default_text");
textview.setText(s);
```

Comment: I have no problems getting my app to update the textview in onCreate with the data stored in SharedPreferences. The problem is onCreate only being called once...

Comment: @litemode: try setting text in onResume() of your activity.that will always be called when you come onto that activity and hence your textview will always be updated.

Comment: Seems this doesn't work :/ And even if it did chances are that the number saved at the point of onResume() will still be the old phone number as the call to the web service takes a moment(1-2 seconds) to proces. Is there a way to bind the data in the textView to automatically update if the data that it binds to changes?

Comment: @litemode: sorry...i didn't get what you want.please be more clear.

Comment: @litemode: you told in your question that you are changing the text in activity which is another that the one which has textview,then simply when you get back to that activity,it will definitely change the text as it was updated in your first activity.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am having a hard time understanding you. I want to make sure that the text shown in a TextView always corresponds to the value of my SharedPreferences (userInfo.getString("number").

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8066/discussion-between-hiral-and-litemode)

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can create your Application class (see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)) and set some variable there that would reflect the supposed value of the textview you want to modify. Then just set that in the onResume of the activity owning that TextView. The variable should persist as long as any of the activities in your application is alive.